# What's wrong with this Callback?

Tags: c++, function, callback

This is my [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7bca488e23333c9):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*CallbackType)(double); 

class LFO
{
private:

public:
    CallbackType target;

    inline void Process() {
        double value = 1.3;
        target(value);
    }
};

class ExternalObject
{
private:

public:
    double mTest = 1.0;

    ExternalObject() {

    }
    ~ExternalObject() {

    }

    inline void PrintValue(double value) {
        cout << "passed: " << value << endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    ExternalObject eo;
    LFO lfo;

    lfo.target = eo.PrintValue;
    lfo.Process();
}
```

I want to execute within LFO's Process the callback PrintValue of ExternalObject. But it seems I cannot pass `lfo.target` in this way? Where am I wrong? (sorry, I'm new to C++; in JavaScript this is the way I'll do it).

Comment: Their types are different, one is a free function and the other one is a member function

Comment: you should add `static` to the `PrintValue` method.

Comment: Using static seems to work! But I don't want to set that method static...

Comment: The correct type is `void (ExternalObject::*)(double)`, but that introduces a dependency on the class. What you should do is use the Standard Library's `function` type.

Comment: So you need to declare a method pointer instead of a function pointer: `typedef void (ExternalObject::*CallbackType)(double);`

Comment: @imreal:can you give to me an example?

Comment: @Franck: as imreal said, this would introduce depencency with ExternalObject, which i dont want.

Comment: Member functions aren't simply associated to some class *instance*; they're associated to a class *type*. If you want to use a pointer to a non-static member function, the type of object that hosts that member must come along for the ride in some fashion. And an object of said-type (or derivation therein) must come along as well if you expect to actually execute that member. There really isn't much to escape that. `static` gets you the function freed of the instance, but at the price of.. there being no instance.

Comment: You can also use `std::function` (C++11 style) or define (C++98 style) a base class `ExternalBase` for `ExternalObject` with a `virtual void PrintValue(double)`. Then define `typedef void (ExternalBase::*CallbackType)(double);` and assign it with `&ExternalBase::printValue`. To call it, you also need an `ExternalBase*` or an `ExternalObject*` inside `LFO` or `LFO::Process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CallbackType` is defined like this:

> ```
> typedef void (*CallbackType)(double);
> ```

This basically is a function taking a `double` and returning nothing (`void`).

When you assign `eo.PrintValue` like this:

> ```
> lfo.target = eo.PrintValue;
> ```

you have a type mismatch: That's because `PrintValue` is a *non-static* member function of the `ExternalObject` class. Non-static member functions have a *"hidden"* **additional** parameter, which is the `this` pointer to the class instance.

It's kind of like the actual declaration of `PrintValue` would be:

```
void ExternalObject::PrintValue(ExternalOject* this, double value)
```

You can fix that making `PrintValue` a **`static` method** of `ExternalObject`, as `static` methods don't have the additional `this` pointer parameter. E.g.:

```
class ExternalObject {
 public:
  // Note: you don't need "inline" here
  static void PrintValue(double value) {
     ...
  }
```

---

**P.S.** Usually when you have callbacks, a common pattern in C++ is to provide an additional `void*` parameter in the callback. This can be used to give some *context* to the callback function, including passing the aforementioned `this` pointer (so a static member-function callback can use the `this` pointer to call a non-static method).

**P.P.S.** That callback style is usually found in C-interface APIs. In C++ you may want to consider [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (e.g.   `std::function<void(double)>`) instead.

---

You may also consider a design with a class with overloaded `operator()` as callback (so called *"functor"*, or *"function object"*), e.g.:

```
#include <functional>  // for std::function
#include <iostream>

class LFO {
public:
    std::function<void(double)> Target;

    void Process() {
        double value = 1.3;
        Target(value);
    }
};

class ValuePrinter {
public:
    void operator()(double value) const {
        std::cout << "passed: " << value << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    LFO lfo;
    lfo.Target = ValuePrinter();
    lfo.Process();
}
```

---

As a different alternative, you can use **`std::bind`** and a placeholder for the `double` parameter, e.g. inside `main`:

```
ExternalObject eo;
LFO lfo;

using namespace std::placeholders;
lfo.Target = std::bind(&ExternalObject::PrintValue, &eo, _1);
lfo.Process();
```

Compilable code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class LFO {
public:
    std::function<void(double)> Target;

    void Process() {
        double value = 1.3;
        Target(value);
    }
};

class ExternalObject {
public:
    double mTest = 1.0;

    ExternalObject() = default;

    void PrintValue(double value) {
        std::cout << "passed: " << value << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    ExternalObject eo;
    LFO lfo;

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    lfo.Target = std::bind(&ExternalObject::PrintValue, &eo, _1);
    lfo.Process();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the method static! If I use `function<double(double)> Target;`, it requires to set static as well to my callback. If I use bind, it throw segmentation fault: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caffd41e8e767c6a

Comment: Nope. My last sample code works fine with std::function and non-static method.

Comment: Oh yes! I did an error on target and Target, sorry! Why using bind works: `lfo.Target = bind(&ExternalObject::PrintValue, &eo, _1);` but if I use normal function `lfo.Target = eo.PrintValue;` it doesn't?

Comment: Because with `bind` I'm binding the `this` pointer (`&eo`), so the non-static barrier went down. It's like I defined another function with only one `double` parameter starting from the non-static method.

Comment: What a "trick". So in fact you are "wrapping" my function of ExternalObject::PrintValue into a function that have as first parameter this (&eo) and as second the value (placeholder) I'll pass, right?

Comment: Yes. (StackOverflow doesn't accept short comments.)

Comment: You may also use lambdas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126855/discussion-between-paizza-and-mr-c64).